# Issue with "WeaponData" in C# Unity Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity project in C#, and I'm encountering an issue with a class named "WeaponData". The compiler is unable to find the type or namespace "WeaponData", even though everything in the code seems fine.

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class WeaponData : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name;
    public WeaponStats stats;
    public GameObject weaponBasePrefab;
    public List<UpgradeData> upgrades;
}

ublic abstract class WeaponBase : MonoBehaviour
{
     public WeaponData weaponData;
     // Rest of the code
}
```

I’ve checked the spelling and case of “WeaponData”, and it seems to be correct. I’ve also tried restarting the IDE and checking the project files, but the issue persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I'm trying to use the "WeaponData" class in my "WeaponBase" class. I expected the code to compile without any issues since "WeaponData" is defined and used correctly in my code. However, the compiler is unable to find the type or namespace "WeaponData", which is causing an error.

Comment: Confirm you have no compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Works on my machine (ofc after excluding public `WeaponStats stats;` and `public List<UpgradeData> upgrades;` because I don't have those classes) Maybe a totally unrelated issue? Try restarting your computer, delete cache etc. Also in the code you provided, you forgot to write "p" in the "public" for `WeaponBase` class if that's the actual code you have to fix that. Also filename should be "WeaponBase.cs" or "WeaponData.cs"